# how to write a console application that calculates the sum of a given number of integers

Tags: c#

Write a console application that calculates the sum of a given number of integers.
The numbers are entered one per line, and the application will read one by one until the user writes the character instead of a number. When the user has typed x, the application knows that all the numbers in the string have been entered and displays their amount.

If the first thing the user enters is the x character, the application will return 0.

Example:

For input:

```
2
5
-3
1
X
```

The console will display:

```
5
```

and this is my code

```
string[] answer = new string[10];
int sum = 0

for (int i = 0; i < answer.Length; i++)
{
    sum += Int32.Parse(answer[i]);

    if (answer[i] == "x")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
    }

    answer[i] = Console.ReadLine();
}

Console.Read();
```

Can anyone tell me why is not working?

Comment: What exactly is not working? You get different result or does an error occur? And shouldn't you ask for input first before iterating over the array?

Comment: Can *you* tell us why its not working? What does it do that you don't expect?

Comment: @Nitu `answer`  array is not initialized with number( they are all set to zero as a default)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the working code (I didn't focus on X but on any char that isn't a number):

```
int n;
int sum = 0;
while (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n))
{
    sum += n;
}
Console.Write(sum ); 
Console.ReadKey();
```

Secondly, your code doesn't work because your array is full of 'null'-s when you try to parse the content of its first cell in 'answer[i]'

Here's a dumb (a bit) fix for your code:

```
string[] answer = new string[10];

//HERE
for (int i = 0; i < answer.Length; i++)
{
    answer[i] = "0";
}    

int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < answer.Length; i++)
{
    sum += Int32.Parse(answer[i]);
    if (answer[i] == "x")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
    }
    answer[i] = Console.ReadLine();
}
Console.Read();
```

Another problem with your code is you don't stop the iteration once "x" is entered, but continue until the end of the array (until it's been 10 times).

Here's kind of a complete fix for your code:

```
string[] answer = new string[10];
for (int i = 0; i < answer.Length; i++)
{
    answer[i] = "0";
}
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < answer.Length; i++)
{
    answer[i] = Console.ReadLine();
    if (answer[i] == "x")
    {
        break;
    }
    sum += Int32.Parse(answer[i]);
}
Console.WriteLine(sum);
Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 1):

Few issues:

1. I think order of your code instructions is not correct. First time when you parse your array element, its not yet initialized.
2. `int sum = 0` is missing `;` at the end.
3. You should always use `TryParse` instead of `Parse`

Try the following code:

```
string[] answer = new string[10];
int sum = 0, number;
for (int i = 0; i < answer.Length; i++)
{
   answer[i] = Console.ReadLine();
   if (answer[i] == "x")
   {
      Console.WriteLine(sum);
      break;
   }
   if(Int32.TryParse(answer[i], out number))
      sum += number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I gave you your terminating 'x'

```
var answer = Console.ReadLine();
var sum = 0;

while (answer != "x")
{    
    if (Int32.TryParse(answer, out var value))
    {
        sum += value;
    }
    answer = Console.ReadLine();    
}
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check for `"x"` *first* since `int.Parse("x")` *throws exception*:

Wrong order (current code):

```
 sum += Int32.Parse(answer[i]); // <- this will throw exception on "x" input

 if (answer[i] == "x") {
   ...
 }
 ...
```

Right order:

```
 if (answer[i] == "x") {
   ...
 }
 else 
   sum += Int32.Parse(answer[i]);
 ...
```

in order to check for syntax errors (e.g. when user inputs `"bla-bla-bla"`) I suggest `int.TryParse` instead of `int.Parse` and let's get rid of the array why should we collect the items (esp. with unwanted restriction of `10` items)?

```
 // long: we don't want overflow, e.g. 2000000000, 1000000000 
 long sum = 0;

 while (true) {
   // Trim() - let's be nice and allow user put leading/trailing spaces
   string input = Console.ReadLine().Trim();

   if (string.Equals("x", input, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
     break;

   if (int.TryParse(input, out var item))
     sum += item;
   else {
     //TODO: Incorrect input, neither integer nor "x" (e.g. "abracadabra")  
   }   
 }

 Console.WriteLine(sum);

 Console.Read();
```